# Order of script execution when using document.write

Tags: javascript, fastclick.js

I need to run a library called Fastclick in order to handle the 300ms click delay that's on mobiles. At the same time, I don't need to run it if I'm not running on mobiles. So I'm looking to do something like this:

```
<head>
        <script>
        var UserAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        if (screen.width < 851 || UserAgent.indexOf('iPad') !== -1 || UserAgent.indexOf('iPhone') || UserAgent.indexOf('Android')) {
        document.write('<script src=\"/ExternalFiles/Fastclick.js\"></script>');
        }
        </script>

        //second script
        <script>
        if (FastClick) {...}
        </script>
</head>
```

As you can see, the second script checks to see if `FastClick` is loaded. On my local machine, this works. However, I'm wondering if it works just because the file is loaded almost instantaneously from the file system (ie no delay) or if in fact, the `document.write` statement triggers the load and the script execution is on hold until that script is loaded. I'm looking for the latter behavior: do scripts that are loaded via `document.write` pause the JavaScript parsing until they're loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you include the file always and call the function only when you need it? Then you don't have to think about any possibility your way involves:

```
<head>
        <script src="/ExternalFiles/Fastclick.js"></script>
        <script>
        var UserAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        if (screen.width < 851 || UserAgent.indexOf('iPad') !== -1 || UserAgent.indexOf('iPhone') || UserAgent.indexOf('Android')) {
                FastClick(...)
        }
        </script>
</head>
```

When a non-mobile browser has loaded the file one time, it's in the cache and doesn't slow down page load.